# Searching List of non-standardized Dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, web-scraping

I scraped a betting website API. Scraping this API returned JSON in what is essentially a list of dictionaries. I am trying to search through this list of dictionaries and return specific bets and odds. Below is my code:

```
Team1 = 'Lechia Gdańsk'

Team2 = 'Sokół Ostróda'


WDW = [{'id': 2853153615, 'label': '1', 'englishLabel': '1', 'odds': 1250, 'participant': 'Lechia Gdańsk', 'type': 'OT_ONE', 'betOfferId': 2244628386, 'changedDate': '2021-01-14T18:52:07Z', 'participantId': 1000020086, 'oddsFractional': '1/4', 'oddsAmerican': '-400', 'status': 'OPEN', 'cashOutStatus': 'ENABLED'}, {'id': 2853153626, 'label': 'X', 'englishLabel': 'X', 'odds': 5750, 'type': 'OT_CROSS', 'betOfferId': 2244628386, 'changedDate': '2021-01-14T18:52:07Z', 'oddsFractional': '19/4', 'oddsAmerican': '475', 'status': 'OPEN', 'cashOutStatus': 'ENABLED'}, {'id': 2853153638, 'label': '2', 'englishLabel': '2', 'odds': 7000, 'participant': 'Sokół Ostróda', 'type': 'OT_TWO', 'betOfferId': 2244628386, 'changedDate': '2021-01-14T18:52:07Z', 'participantId': 1001302448, 'oddsFractional': '6/1', 'oddsAmerican': '600', 'status': 'OPEN', 'cashOutStatus': 'ENABLED'}]


unisoccerWDWTeam1 = next((item['odds']/1000 for item in WDW if item['participant'] == Team1), None)

unisoccerWDWTeam2 = next((item['odds']/1000 for item in WDW if item['participant'] == Team2), None)

unisoccerWDWDraw = next((item['odds']/1000 for item in WDW if item['label'] == 'X'), None)
```

I use next() and dictionary comprehension to search for a matching team name and then return the odds from the list of dictionaries. The issue is the dictionaries are not uniform within the list and so when my code encounters a dictionary without the key I'm searching for it returns an error. In this case WDW[1] does not have 'participant' in the dictionary. Is there a way to avoid this problem or skip dictionaries that do not contain the Key:Value pair I am searching for? I am considering simply writing nested for loops maybe with try except blocks to avoid this however this seems like a slow and inelegant solution. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what output are you looking for?

Comment: `item.get('participant', None)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply avoid the exception, you can use item.get('participant'), which will return None if "participant" doesn't exist, rather than raising an exception. (Which is similar to the *None* default you are using for you *next* call.

Depending on how you implement the loop, this should allow you to silently skip dictionaries that don't contain the keys you are looking for.

This would be something like:

```
unisoccerWDWTeam1 = next((item['odds']/1000 for item in WDW if item.get('participant') == Team1), None)
```

Code not tested, but should get you started.